# How to handle the TextBlock Click within the Grid Control in WPF using prism 6?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, binding, prism

I am having an scenario where I show a window to the user and ask them to choose anything by left click on it. See attached pix[image]

So in this Window I have corresponding WindowViewModel following a Prism 6.1.0 framework. I want to bind this click event to the Grid instead of Binding with the each TextBlock each. Is it possible?

if yes, I tried this. In the grid Control my code is this.

```
    <Grid x:Name="Locals1">
    <Grid.InputBindings>
        <MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftClick"
        Gesture="LeftClick" Command="{Binding MouseCommand, 
        Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=Locals1, 
           Path=SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
     />
     </Grid.InputBindings>
<TextBlock Focusable="True" text="textblock1" />
<TextBlock Focusable="True" text="textblock2" />
<TextBlock Focusable="True" text="textblock3" />
<TextBlock Focusable="True" text="textblock4" />
</Grid>
```

And in the WindowViewModel I have a code like this.

```
public WindowViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
{
    MouseCommand = new DelegateCommand<string>(OnConnection);
}

private void OnConnection(string obj)
    {
        ... 
    }
```

But I don't get the TextBlock.Text value in that OnConnection method. Is it really so tough? What I know about WPF and MVVM that we can handle the child click event in the parent control itself. This will reduce duplicate codes.

I know I am doing something definitely wrong. But I don't know what exactly. How can I pass this value from WindowViewModel to the MainWindowViewModel?

I can achieve the same functionality using a binding each in all the textblocks but that will not serve the purpose of Prism. basically all the text Block click events functionality is same only the value of the textblock will be different.

thanks

Comment: I would approach this using Behaviors. Here's a useful link :) https://www.jayway.com/2013/03/20/behaviors-in-wpf-introduction/

Comment: Did you try to pass the text block value as command parameter?

Comment: I already posted that I passed the `CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=Locals1, Path=SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"` But no use.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, i don't like my answer, but:

You use `Grid`, not `DataGrid` and similar, so what is `SelectedItem` in you context?!

I cant invent how to use pretty binding in this case, so i changed command

```
public DelegateCommand<Object> MouseCommand { get; set; }

public WindowViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
{
    MouseCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(OnConnection);
}
```

and

```
private void OnConnection(object obj)
{
    var text = GetTextFromClickOnGrid(obj);
}

private string GetTextFromClickOnGrid(object obj)
{
    var grid = obj as Grid;
    if (grid != null)
    {
        var mousePos = Mouse.GetPosition(grid);
        var itemUnderMouse = VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(grid, mousePos);
        var textBlock = itemUnderMouse.VisualHit as TextBlock;
        if (textBlock != null)
        {
            return textBlock.Text;
        }
    }

    var textBlockUnderMouse = Mouse.DirectlyOver as TextBlock;
    if (textBlockUnderMouse != null)
    {
        return textBlockUnderMouse.Text;
    }

    return string.Empty;
}
```

and xaml

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1" x:Name="Locals1">
            <Grid.InputBindings>
                <MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftClick"
                              Gesture="LeftClick" 
                              Command="{Binding MouseCommand, 
                                                Mode=TwoWay,                            
                                        UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                              CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=Locals1}"
                 />
            </Grid.InputBindings>
            <TextBlock Focusable="True" Text="textblock1" Height="30" Width="100" Margin="115,45,302,84" />
            <TextBlock Focusable="True" Text="textblock2" Height="30" Width="100" Margin="115,10,302,119"/>
            <TextBlock Focusable="True" Text="textblock3" Height="30" Width="100" Margin="10,45,407,84"/>
            <TextBlock Focusable="True" Text="textblock4" Height="30" Width="100" Margin="10,10,407,119"/>

        </Grid>
```

Comment: How can you use DataGrid and achieve the same display like I mentioned above and achieve the same functionality, any idea?

Comment: Considering that all the strings {"textblock1", "textBlock2", "textblock3", ... } are fixed constants strings. tb1, tb2, tb3 will be in Column 1. tb4, tb5, tb6 in column 2, tb7, tb8,tb9 in column 3 etc. Its better to put in a <grid> with row definitions and column defintions isn't it?

Comment: @Debhere You can do the same with 3 DataGrid or 3 ListBox and use `SelectedItem`. Or `Grid` and my solution. I don't see how to eat all chocolates at the same time.

Answer (score -1):

i think you looking this:

```
   <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="LeftClick">
          <command:EventToCommand
            Command="{Binding Main.MouseCommand ,
              Mode=OneWay,
              Source={StaticResource Locator}}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
      </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

binding what you want. Any event to almost any command.

ViewModelLocator:

```
public class ViewModelLocator
    {
        static ViewModelLocator()
        {
            ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MainViewModel>();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the Main property.
        /// </summary>
        public MainViewModel Main
        {
            get
            {
                return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MainViewModel>();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I didn't get it fully. i: must be some namespace?  could you please elaborate how this textBlock value will be passed on to MainWindowViewModel from WindowViewModel?

Comment: First of all - what is WindowViewModel? Window DataContext? Do you have ViewModelLocator or something?

Comment: This Window having a WindowViewModel for the Datacontext of this window. yes in prism ViewModelLocator is present and it takes care of it. this Window Loads from a MainWindowViewModel. How Can I pass the textBlock.text value to the MainWindowViewModel subscribe event?

Comment: in code snippet: Locator  = ViewModelLocator, static resource(оr static class, whatever). And Main = MainViewModel (property of ViewModelLocator) and  MouseCommand =Command of it. Is it works for you?